# How can I make Chrome save a Base64 encoded image as a png within a new window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Chrome has a challenge with saving `Base64` encoded images when those images are written to a blank window.

I have a `canvas` I want to create an image from and allow my users to download with a simple "right click" of the mouse and "Save As" dialog.

I've got javascript code that works as desired in FF (60+) and MS Edge listed below:

```
function download() {
  ctx1.drawImage(c2,0,0);
  ctx1.drawImage(c3,0,0);
  var image="<img src='"+planner1.toDataURL()+"' alt='canvas image'/>";
  var tab = window.open();
  tab.document.write(image);
}
```

HTML button to activate the function is below:

`<span class="style2"><button class="button2" id="page1" style="float:right;margin-right:10px" onclick="download();document.body.style.cursor='wait'">Open Image</button></span>`

The window/tab opens in Chrome when this runs and the user can right click on the image and select "save as" when the dialog pops up.

However, no follow-on dialog pops up asking the user where to save the image.  In order to actually save the image a user has to right click on the image and select "open the image in new tab".  This opens yet another window/tab, which the user can then actually save the image as a `png` file.

Not sure why this is Chrome default behavior, but here I am.

From what I can gather it may be because Chrome interprets the `javascript` as plain "data" written within the new window which just so happens it can interpret and display as a `Base64` encoded image once the page loads fully.  It takes the user another step to get Chrome to open the now interpreted and displayed image as an actual image that can be saved locally.

It also may be because a default file name is not specified anywhere.

Both FF and Edge create a default name within the "Save As" dialog.

I want Chrome to operate like FF and Edge in this situation, so users don't get confused.

Appreciate any recommendations if folks have run across something like this before and can help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This ended up being a small bit of a hack job but adding a small delay (500ms) was all that was needed for this to work across all modern browsers ... using download.js v4.2, by dandavis.

```
function getPNG() {
    ctx1.drawImage(c2,0,0);
    ctx1.drawImage(c3,0,0);
    var imgData1 = planner1.toDataURL("image/png");
    download(imgData1, "Planner.png", "image/png");
    window.setTimeout(reload, 500);

function reload(){
    window.location.href = '../php/mplanner.php?pln=<?php echo $user ?>';
    }
}
```